# ORA-00979 in sqlalchemy when using group_by

Tags: python, sql, oracle, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a query, which makes an average of the power based on the date,
however sqlalchemy is bringing me the following error:

**sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression**

This is my sqlalchemy query:

```
result = db.session.query(
func.to_char(myTable.datetime, 'DD.MM.YY'), func.avg(myTable.power))
.group_by(func.to_char(myTable.datetime, 'DD.MM.YY'))
.order_by(func.to_char(myTable.datetime, 'DD.MM.YY'))
.all()
```

This is the query in sqldeveloper, which works there, but not in my flask app:

```
SELECT 
  to_char(myTable.datetime, 'DD.MM.YY'), avg(myTable.power)
FROM 
  myTable 
GROUP BY 
  to_char(myTable.datetime, 'DD.MM.YY') 
ORDER BY
  to_char(myTable.datetime, 'DD.MM.YY');
```

When I use `extract`, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62576842/ora-00979-when-using-group-by-with-sqlalchemy) post, it works, but I want to get a date as string.

Comment: could you use 3 extracts to get year, month and day and concatenate them if extract works?

Comment: Why would you want to order by the date formatted as `DD.MM.YY`? You would get rows in the order `01.01.00` then `01.01.01` ... (with increasing year) then `01.02.00` ... (increasing month) then finally `02.01.00` (increasing day). Surely that would be very difficult for humans to analyse and you would be better to use the format `YYYY-MM-DD` to have the rows in chronological order or even better, to not convert the `DATE` to a string and use the `TRUNC` function.

Comment: If you did want that date format then: `SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(datetime), 'DD.MM.YY'), AVG(power) FROM mytable GROUP BY TRUNC(datetime) ORDER BY TRUNC(datetime);`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment of MT0 the `TRUNC` function works for me. My sqlalchemy query now looks like this:

```
result = db.session.query(
func.to_char(func.trunc(myTable.datetime)), func.avg(myTable.power))
.group_by(func.trunc(myTable.datetime))
.order_by(func.trunc(myTable.datetime))
.all()
```